# Using MagicalRecord, how do I get data out of NSArray and into a NSManagedObject?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I am using MagicalRecord to work with Core Data objects.  I am having problems with retrieving Core Data objects using the NSArray that MR puts them into... I can't seem to get the data out of the array and into a NSManagedObject so I can work with it.  Here is my code:

```
        //  create the predicate
    NSArray *apptDataArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSPredicate *predicate =  ([NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((aStartTime > %@) AND (aStartTime <= %@))", startDate, endDate]);

    //  find all appointments with that selected date
    apptDataArray = [AppointmentInfo MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate];

    //  now find the appointments for the selected date and put them in the schedule
    if(apptDataArray.count > 0) {
        for (NSManagedObject *AppointmentInfo in apptDataArray) {
            NSLog(@"\n\n-->apptDataArray: %@", apptDataArray);

        }
    }
```

This is the definition for AppointmentInfo which is in a different class:

```
@interface AppointmentInfo : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * aStartTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * aEndTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * aServiceTech;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * aApptKey;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *aShortDate;
```

Somehow, I need to get to the data which is in the returned array and place it in AppointmentInfo.   I have tried all kinds of permutations, looked in Google and SO, but I couldn't find anything.  I'm stumped!  How do I do it?

Comment: What exactly are the symptoms of the failure?

Comment: It's not a failure... I just don't know how to get the NSArray data returned from MR into AppointmentInfo so I can get the separate fields (ie aStartTime, aEndTime) and work with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but
the result `apptDataArray` of the fetch request is just an array of `AppointmentInfo` objects, so you can access individual objects with

```
AppointmentInfo *appt = [apptDataArray objectAtIndex:i]; // 0 <= i < apptDataArray.count
```

or enumerate all objects of the result array with

```
for (AppointmentInfo *appt in apptDataArray) {
    NSLog(@"startTime=%@, endTime=%@", appt.aStartTime, appt.aEndTime);
}
```